# Using Vagrant version 1.3.5 I keep getting an error about /var/chef/cache not existing when I try to bring up a VM

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using recipes that were working previously, with an older version of Vagrant, but after updating I'm getting the error that /var/chef/cache doesn't exist. I tried updating my recipes to the current ones on opscode, but I still get the error.

I'm not a Vagrant pro or anything, is there something I can do to force the creation of the /var/chef/cache directory before the recipes are processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by adding these lines to the config file:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "mkdir /var/chef"
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "mkdir /var/chef/cache"
```

Comment: You can replace this with a single, idempotent command: `mkdir -p /var/chef/cache`